# Why does Gimp show a second icon when running it?

Tags: unity, 18.04, icons, gimp

[image]

Why does Gimp `2.10.4` show a second icon when running it?? One is brown and one is grey next to it. Is this a gui bug or a useful feature for whatever?

After moving the grey icon whithin the launcher/dock and then closing gimp and reopening it, there are even more of these icons :-D

[image]

I would like to create a Github issue for this, but it seems as there were so many issues for gimp that they closed the issues option on Github :-D

Comment: Might be interesting to mention if you are using a snap version of gimp. Doesn't look like any of the "traditional" icon dupe issues.

Comment: The Ubuntu Software Center doesnt show me a gimp installation at all, so what is the correct way to find out whether it is a snap or something else? I still wonder why there is no indication in the Software Center which package manager was used for whatever. So confusing...

Comment: Run `snap list` in the terminal, and look for `gimp` in the output.

Comment: This is what it returns to me: `core  16-2.34.3  5145  stable    canonical  core` 
 Name = `core`, Notes = `core`. Seems like I have an app installed called `core` :-D

Comment: The GitHub repo is a "mirror" of the real repo which is on Gnome's own GitLab server. Bugs are handled [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues). To install a decent Gimp on your 18.04 use [Otto's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) which also features the most useful Gimp plugins (gmic and gimp-plugin-registry).